# Button label disappers after disable action

Tags: jquery, css, disabled-input

This is a very weird problem am facing

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="buttonobj" class="some class" value ="Button Name"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){

 $buttonObject = $('#buttonObj");
 $buttonObject.button('disable');

});
```

When I run this code and watch the HTML in firebug, am getting

```
<input type="button" id=buttonobj" class="some class" value =""/>
```

The value vanishes.

What does the disable do here. how can it change the value. Is it possible for a css to change a button value??

Am Using jQuery-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the problem!

No one answered the question

**What does the disable do here. how can it change the value. Is it possible for a css to change a button value??**

The answer, it was a custom made jQuery Ui. On calling `button.disable` function, it is implicitly setting these two classes

`ui-button-disabled` `ui-state-disabled`

Thanks for all solution here, but I know all those ways of doing. Since it was a code which I was taking over from some one , I was not supposed to change but just find , Why it was not working while it was being integrated

Answer (score 3):

There are a few mistakes in the code. Try this: (I fixed up some missing/wrong quotes, and changed the jquery "disable button" line to something I know works, as I'm not familiar with the code you used)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="buttonobj" class="class" value="Button Name" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
   $buttonObject = $("#buttonObj");
   $buttonObject.prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but you should use `prop` when setting the `disabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

To change value of disable attribute,  use following:

```
$(function(){

 $buttonObject = $("#buttonobj");
 $buttonObject.prop('disabled', true);
 alert($buttonObject.val());

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mYz3b/1/

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes in the html, missing quote on id attrib and space between value and equals

So it should be:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonObj" class="some class" value=" Button Name"/>
```

For the jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $buttonObject = $("#buttonObj");
    $buttonObject.attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

And use `$buttonObject.removeAttr("disabled");` if you want to re-enable it.

Edit:

Also the id on the button and in the jQuery didn't match updated code.

Edit:

You could do the same thing with plain javascript:

```
function someFunc(){
    document.getElementById("buttonObj").disabled = "disabled";
}
```

Comment: What's the second dot for in the `$buttonObject..attr` bit?

Comment: @Simon M Typo, fixed it, nice catch +1'd

Comment: The space was a typo. Also, the $.disable is working in other pages. Now I integrate with other application, some css clash...

Comment: @madhairsilence I doubt css has anything to do with your problem. Spotted another typo updated code and gave an alternative. This is the way I do these things myself (I think it's simpler than jQuery for this job).

Comment: I know there are lot of ways to do things. This application is already working. Now am integrating it with some other application. Now its not working. Change the code is not an option. Find the one which clashes and remove it.